# Sample or Population Standard Deviation (SD) While Calculating SD Regarding All Variables' Variance Inflation Factor Values

Tags: standard-deviation, sample, population, variance-inflation-factor

**What Was I Trying to Do?**

I was calculating the Variance Inflation Factors (VIFs) of all variables in a data set. Then, I was interested to calculate the mean and standard deviation (SD) of VIFs of all variables. The problem created while I was calculating the SD.

**Then, What Did Confuse Me?**

During calculation of SD of VIFs regarding all variables, I was confused whether I should use formula of population SD or sample SD? The reason behind the confusion is that here I am considering all variables. Thus, I think I can use the formula of population SD. However, as in each variable, only about 10,000+ participants' data are available (which is very less relative to the total population), I asked myself "how can I use the formula of population SD?".

**Then, My Question**

Should I use the formula of population SD while calculating SD of all variables' variance inflation factors? If yes, then why not sample SD? If not, then, why do you think that sample SD is appropriate in this case?

**How Did I Try to Get the Answer of My Question?**

I have read some articles and some questions of StackExchange regarding sample and population standard deviation. However, these (what I have read) articles and questions talked about standard deviation of a variable, not standard deviation of a particular value (e.g. VIFs) of all variables.

*Thanks for reading!*

Comment: If you want to use the sample SD, that means you hope it estimates the SD of something.  Could you tell us what that something is and how it would be of any use in analyzing this dataset?  That could help in determining what the appropriate procedure ought to be.

Comment: At first, I am sorry for late reply and thanks for your comment. Here, I want to know the SD of variance inflation factors (VIF). Thus, "something" is variance inflation factor.

Comment: That doesn't really respond to my question: if all you want is to *compute* the SD of the VIFs, then do so.  But your post suggests you want to estimate some property of the VIFs where your data are viewed as a random sample.  It is difficult to see how the SD of a set of VIFs would be very useful or informative in most circumstances, making me wonder what you are really trying to accomplish.